# Submitting form in foreach loop using php and jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to submit forms in foreach loop using PHP and jQuery. But the form gets only the first value in the loop.

I tried to unbind the form using `$('#admin_status').unbind().submit();`
But still there is no change in the form value. 
Any help ?

PHP

```
<? foreach ($results as $links) {
$linkid=$links["id"];

?>
<div id="admin_status">
  <form class="form-horizontal">

      <input type="hidden" name="action" value="status_entry">
      <input type="hidden" name="link_id" value="<?=$linkid?>">
      <input type="text" name="status_update">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary js-status-submit">Status Update</button>
      </form>
 </div>
<?
    } ?>
```

jQuery

```
$( "body" ).on( "click", ".js-status-submit", function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
     $('#admin_status').find('form').attr('id','admin_status_update');
                   var formData = $('#admin_status_update').serialize();
                     $.post("../pages/submit_idea.php",formData)
                     .done(function( data ) {
                        location.reload();

     });  
  });
```

Comment: Ids have to be **unique**

Comment: In addition to what @Andreas already said.. you are using `$linkid` inside the form.. but the php variable is `$links`

Comment: sorry, that was already assigned to $linkid. I didnt get which id to be unique ?

Comment: <div id="admin_status"> id must be unique for entire document ..

Comment: why use jquery to submit form ?

Comment: Id is unique for the entire document.

Answer (score 0):

**Give a form name** `<form class="form-horizontal" name="myform">`

```
$( "form [name='myform']" ).on( "submit", function(event) {
          event.preventDefault();

                       var formData = $(this).serialize();
                         $.post("../pages/submit_idea.php",formData)
                         .done(function( data ) {
                            location.reload();

         });  
      });
```